# Vectorization- Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

Given a vector

```
X = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]
```

I would like to generate a vector such

```
Y = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5]
```

So far what I have got is

```
idx = find(diff(X))
Y   = [1:idx(1) 1:idx(2)-idx(1) 1:length(X)-idx(2)]
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant(robust) solution?

Comment: So what makes you think that this isn't robust or elegant?

Comment: This assumes that  `unique(X) = 3`

Comment: Ah I see.  You should probably update your problem statement to reflect that.  That artificial example is very deceiving.  You should state that the vector `X` can generalize to include more than three unique elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach with `diff`, `find` & `cumsum` for a generic case -

```
%// Initialize array of 1s with the same size as input array and an 
%// intention of using cumsum on it after placing "appropriate" values
%// at "strategic" places for getting the final output.
out = ones(size(X))

%// Find starting indices of each "group", except the first group, and
%// by group here we mean run of identical numbers.
idx = find(diff(X))+1

%// Place differentiated and subtracted values of indices at starting locations
out(idx) = 1-diff([1 idx])

%// Perform cumulative summation for the final output
Y = cumsum(out)
```

Sample run -

```
X =
     1     1     1     1     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     5
Y =
     1     2     3     4     1     2     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     1
```

---

Just for fun, but *customary* `bsxfun` based alternative solution -

```
%// Logical mask with each column of ones for presence of each group elements
mask = bsxfun(@eq,X(:),unique(X(:).'))  %//'

%// Cumulative summation along columns and use masked values for final output
vals = cumsum(mask,1)
Y = vals(mask)
```

Comment: Nice.  This was what I was going to suggest. +1

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
Y = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, X, X.')), 1);
```

This works as follows:

1. Compare each element with all others (`bsxfun(...)`).
2. Keep only comparisons with current or previous elements (`triu(...)`).
3. Count, for each element, how many comparisons are `true` (`sum(..., 1)`); that is, how many elements, up to and including the current one, are equal to the current one.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you! Not memory-efficient, but it's a one-liner and it uses `bsxfun`! :-)

Comment: @Divakar Your answer is the way to go. I had to explore some other path :-)

Comment: Divakar is proud that you are using his pet!

Comment: @rayryeng Well I am sure Luis takes great pleasure in taking "my pet" for walks often! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another method is using the function `unique`

like this:

```
[unqX ind Xout] = unique(X)

Y = [ind(1):ind(2) 1:ind(3)-ind(2) 1:length(X)-ind(3)]
```

Whether this is more elegant is up to you.

---

A more robust method will be:

```
[unqX ind Xout] = unique(X)
for ii = 1:length(unqX)-1
    Y(ind(ii):ind(ii+1)-1) = 1:(ind(ii+1)-ind(ii));
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't agree with this approach.  It's a good attempt though, but this essentially does what the OP is doing - you're substituting `find` with `unique`.  This assumes that you only have three unique elements.  What if you had more than 3 possible elements?  What would you do with `X = [1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 9]`?

Comment: It works in the example of the original question, for your example you can add a loop using the length of the uinique number vector (unqX).

Comment: A loop is something the OP doesn't want, hence more elegant and robust.... but you are correct, a loop would work... but I find Divakar's answer more MATLAB-centric.